# Creating instances of model objects with database defaults in Play

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I am experimenting with Anorm library of Playframework v2 in Scala.
 I have a case class like below

```
case class User (
  id:Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, // auto increment value in mysql   
  name: String
  updated_at: Date // assigned through a trigger by Database
  )

val testUser = new User(NotAssigned:Pk[Long], "Ali", null)
```

Is it find to use **null** for fields such as updated_at which their values are assigned directly through DB ? How about using something like Pk[Date] ? I suppose I don't understand the Pk type in Anorm correctly.

I appreciate your comments,

Answer (score 2):

I think assigning `null` values is never a good idea. I'm using a default date instead. You should then omit the default values when constructing new values of type `User` (the `new` keyword is unnecessary for Scala's case classes):

```
case class User (
  id:Pk[Long] = NotAssigned,
  name: String
  updated_at: Date = new Date(0) //1970-01-01
  )

val testUser = User("Ali")
```

Answer (score 1):

If this value is automatically set by your database you should not need to set it by yourself. Thus, it should not appear in your *write* operations.